# Socket.io on https server gets net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: node.js, socket.io, timeout

I have a node.js program using socket.io and it's on https server.

This program works fine on my local computer, but it gives 
**GET https://aaa.bbb.ccc:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LpfRXy7 net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT** error when it's on server.

'https://aaa.bbb.ccc' is the server url.
Down below are both sides of code.

How could I solve this problem ?

server side (app.js)

```
const port = 3000;
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  //~~~
}
server.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Connected, port: '+port);
});
```

client side (client.js)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script> <!--in header-->
var socket = io.connect('https://aaa.bbb.ccc:3000/');
```

Answer (score 0):

The io.connect('https://aaa.bbb.ccc:3000/') may not be correct.  Try running on localhost first:

io.connect('http://localhost:3000/');